# How to build XPath with [0-9] regex expression

Tags: xpath, hp-uft

Hi is there anyone can help me how to build the xpath for below 2 different XPath values?

```
//*[@id="EditorPanel"]/div[3]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]
//*[@id="EditorPanel"]/div[4]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]
```

Im thinking something like

```
//*[@id="EditorPanel"]/div[3-4]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]
```

Comment: I need the XPath values to identify objects using UFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div[3]` is just an abbreviation of `div[position() = 3]`, so you can use

```
//*[@id="EditorPanel"]/div[position() = 3 or position() = 4]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]
```